# Using ImageResizer to write a new image via handler ashx

Tags: c#, asp.net, handler, ashx, imageresizer

I'm trying to use [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/) which is so far a really good image cropper when I use it directly on an image like so:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg?height=300" />
```

But when I'm trying to use a ashx handler to write out the image, I'm experiencing some problems. Here is my code:

`ImageHandler.ashx`

```
    string filePath = (HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + context.Session["currentdirectory"]);
    string file = context.Request.QueryString["name"];

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(filePath + "/" + file, ms, new Instructions("height=300"), false, true));


    context.Response.Write(ms.ToArray());
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    context.Response.AddHeader(
       "Content-Disposition",
       "inline; filename=" + file);
```

It seems when using above code, the image is broken, or as mozilla firefox says: The image 'myimage.jpg' cannot be shown, because it contains errors.

So I guess that the byte array it gets is apparently wrong?

Do I send a wrong type to `Response.Write` or am i just using `ImageBuilder` the wrong way?
Or what could be to solution to my problem here?

Edit:
Btw writing it to a file instead of memorystream works, so I must do something wrong when trying to write it via handler?

```
    var to = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "/" + file;
    ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(filePath + "/" + file, to, new Instructions("height=300")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/img");
var file = context.Request.QueryString["name"];

using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ImageBuilder.Current.Build( new ImageJob( filePath + "/" + file, ms, new Instructions( "height=300" ), false, true ) );

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    context.Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + file );
    ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
}
```

or just use:

```
context.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
```

this works also

Comment: Omg yes i was not even writing binary then? Thank you this is the correct answer :-)

Comment: Keep in mind [that it's a very bad practice to wrap ImageResizer in a handler](http://imageresizing.net/docs/best-practices) considering it provides an HttpModule to *properly* handle image serving itself.

Answer (score -1):

does

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(...)
```

run in an seperate thread? if it does,
then this could be the problem, you wrote something to the stream, before the task is finished.

Maybe there is callback or a synchronized method to run the image resizer.

Comment: Well it doesnt seem like its in a seperate thread. I tried to put `Thread.Sleep(10000)` right after the `ImageBuilder.Current.Build` so shouldn't that make sure that it managed to do it all? Also `ms` seems to have same size every time i debug

Comment: It's not named Async or Begin/End, why would you think it's asynchronous?

Comment: I dont know this library,
but I associated the term "...Job" with something like a pipeline,
which handles the "jobs" maybe async (by default)